# SQL - SQL statement has been terminated if one insert into row is incorrect

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-insert, bulkinsert

I'm trying to insert hundreds of rows into a table using a query like:

```
Insert INTO tableX (column1, colum2)
VALUES 
((SELECT sysID FROM tableY where ID = var1), 1)
((SELECT sysID FROM tableY where ID = var2), 1)
et cetera
```

Now let's say var88 doesn't exist, it will return NULL as sysID, however I can't insert a NULL into column1 so I get an error and the whole insert into query will be terminated. Is there a way to cancel the whole termination and just skip the rows where sysID = NULL? I'm sure I can do this by first doing a proper select, filtering out the NULL rows and THEN do the insert into, however I'm wondering if there is an other way to do this.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the following instead, using a [`INSERT INTO SELECT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/insert-transact-sql):

```
INSERT INTO tableX (column1, colum2) 
    SELECT sysID, 1 
    FROM tableY 
    WHERE ID IN (va1, var2) AND NOT sysID IS NULL
```

Comment: The query needs a bit of formatting to show how easy it is to write an `INSERT INTO` query from a `SELECT .. FROM`

Answer (score 0):

Where/how are you getting the var1 (etc) variables for your values?

You can convert this to:

```
Insert INTO tableX (column1, colum2)
VALUES 
Select SELECT sysID, 1
Where ID IN (var1, var2, etc..)
WHERE sysID is not null
```

Or build this into a loop somehow (depending on where/how your var1 etc are coming from

Comment: I generate the SQL query in Excel

Comment: @vincentkleine it's a *lot* easier to generate a comma-separated list of values in Excel than it is to generate SQL statements.

Comment: So you are building out the SQL with function builders to combine columns?  Then paste into Excel?  Easier way is to just build out commas and copy/paste that into the WHERE ID IN (past list of values here).  So in Excel set function to just something simple like =ColWithVar&","  This should just create your value with a comma.  Then paste all that into your IN statement and remove the last comma for final value.